# UIImageView to UIImage?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiimageview, uiimage

I want to upload an image to a server. I can do this and it works with a `UIImage`. However, I want to upload the current image being displayed in my application which is within a `UIImageView`.

How can I pass, or temporarily store the `UIImageView` image within an `UIImage`? I have tried the following however it does not work.

```
UIImage *myImage = imageView.image;
```

Comment: I don't see any reason why this shouldn't work. What's the problem when you try?

Comment: is your image maybe an animated image? normally it shout be possible to get a `UIImage` out of the image property of an `UIImageView` is the resulting image nil?

Comment: No the image is not animated. The user is able to select photos from the photo library and then it gets displayed within an uiimageview. I want to place that photo within an uiimage

Comment: what's the behavior of doing what you described? If you do `NSLog` on `myImage` does it return empty?

Comment: Does using the following produce any different results:           `UIImage *imageToSend = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:imageView.image.CGImage];`

Comment: Please edit your question to explain what "does not work" means. What happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have should work, what kind of error are you getting? Alternatively you could try this...

```
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageView.image)];
```

or even better...

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageView.image)];
```

but why do you even need to allocate a UIImage when you already have one in the UIImageView? Just use imageView.image directly...

Comment: Worked perfect for me...Good job

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure yet why accessing the image property directly is not working for you, however alternatively you can render the image view into a bitmap context and then create a new image from the context. The code would be similar to:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>  // necessary for referencing CALayers
...
CGSize imageSize = imageView.bounds.size; 
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSize, NO, 0);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[imageView.image.layer renderInContext:context];
UIImage *myImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

See [Technical Q&A QA1703 - Screen Capture in UIKit Applications](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1703/_index.html)